# Is there a way to set cookies or local storage from variables in Playwright?

Tags: node.js, cookies, chromium, playwright

I want to be able to set my own cookie variables before I even start loading up a Chromium/Firefox driver and have these variables be sent to that driver so that I can set up my driver to utilise API calls to log in to a secure page without having to do so manually or save a `.json` file

I know that you can use Playwright's `BrowserContext.addCookies()` feature to add cookies into the current browser context; but I noticed that, upon opening up the inspector view of said browser, it is not actually being saved in the inspector:

```js
var browser = await chromium.launch({
  headless: false,
  args: ['--start-fullscreen']
});

var context = await browser.newContext();

await context.addCookies([
  {name: "[MY-TOKEN]", value: [MY-TOKEN-VALUE], domain: "[MY-DOMAIN]", path: "/"},
  {name: "[MY-TOKEN-2]", value: [MY-TOKEN-2-VALUE], domain: "[MY-DOMAIN]", path: "/"}
]);

var page = await context.newPage();
```

I then utilise my inspector view to see if my browser has captured my cookies and saved them to the page; but to no success (NOTE: some cookies have been blacked out for security reasons, but these aren't the cookies I'm looking for):
[image: Screenshot Here]

Why am I not seeing the cookies I am expecting in the inspector view of my browser, when I run my Node.JS suite?

Likewise, I also want to set local storage variables prior to loading the browser context without having to set a storageState and I do NOT want to use a `.json` file to do so. Is there a way to do this as well?